Jealousy over pizzas
There are $10$ dudes and $10$ pizzas. Each dude gets a different pizza. Assume that each of them is getting their third-best pizza, but besides that, the preferences of dudes over pizzas are random.
Suppose that dudes $8$, $9$, and $10$ get pizzas nobody else prefers to their own. I am wondering what is the probability that one of the other dudes ($1-7$) gets a pizza that:

No other dude in $\{1,\ldots,7\}$ prefers his pizza to their own, and
At least one dude in $\{8,9,10\}$ prefers his pizza to their own.

My attempt at calculations: consider the probability that event 1. occurs for say, dude $7$. This is, we are looking at the probability that dudes $1-6$ do not prefer his pizza. This is the probability that dudes in $1-6$ do not think dude $7$'s pizza is the top or second-top pizza.
Let's focus on the probability that dude 1 does not envy dude 7.
If everything is random, this should be $\frac{4}{6}$. Note this is not $\frac{7}{9}$ because we know that dude 1 prefers pizza 1 over pizzas 8, 9, and 10.
and therefore the probability that no dude $1-6$ prefers dude $7$'s pizza is simply $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6$ right?
Now we need the probability of event ii) at least one dude $8-10$ prefers dude $7$'s pizza. This is the same as 1 minus the probability that no dude in $8-10$ prefers dude 7's pizza. This is: $1-\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^3$.
Therefore, the probability that dude $7$'s get such a pizza (not envied by $1-6$ but envied by either $8$, $9$, $10$) is: $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6\times\left[1-\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^3\right]=0.056$, so the expected number of dudes in ($1-7$) who are not envied by their peers but envied by some dude in ($8-10$) should be: $0.0558 \times 7= 0.3906$.
Does that sound reasonable? It somehow seems too low.
A generalization: If I have $n$ dudes, and everybody is getting their $k$-best pizza, how many dudes are not envied by anyone in expectation?

The wording is unclear to me. What does it mean for someone to prefer his pizza to their own. Who is the subject in "his", who are the subjects of "their"? Also, do they all get exactly their thirdly highest ranking, since that would already give only a single configuration? What is the randomness here, and what does the added regularities apply to. Without clarifications it is hard to guess what is meant!

There is one configuration of which dude gets which pizzas, but the dudes' preferences over others pizzas are random.

So let the dudes be $A_1,...,A_{10}$. They WLOG have pizzas $A_1:B_1,...,A_{10}:B_{10}$. Given this setup we are randomizing over ways they can all have their own pizza as nr. 3, so for instance: $$A_1:[B_3, B_2, B_1]$$ received a pizza matching his third prefence. Another solution for $A_1$ is $$A_1:[B_{10},B_{5}, B_1]$$ as long as the one he got is nr. 3. What else?

It's a bit strange that it seems like the dudes' preferences are selected after the pizzas are known. That is, the probability distribution as you describe is not necessarily the same as the conditional probabilities from randomly assigning each dude one of the $10!$ preferences lists, and then looking at only the cases where no two dudes have the same pizza in third place on their list. Still, it's entirely possible to work out the answer the way you specified it.

You made an error in the 8-10 part. The probability of "at least one" is not found by adding, if more than one is a possibility.

As already pointed out in the latest comment, the error is indeed in the 8-10 part. The probability here is of $2/3$ for each of dudes 8-10 since dude 7's pizza has $2/3$ chance of being in their top 2. Therefore:
$$
1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=\frac{19}{27}
$$
Hence the probability for dude 7 is:
$$
\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^6 \cdot \frac{19}{27} \approx 0.1037
$$
So we then multiply this by the expected number of dudes (1-7) who meet both conditions therefore:
$$
0.1037 \cdot 7 \approx 0.7259
$$
I hope this clarifies, let me know for any futher doubt!
